Having some issues with coding a combat system for my text based adventure game. Dicerolls and combat loop not working
This code is for my final c project. I feel like I've gone a bit over my head in terms of coding the combat system, as combining all these loops and functions together was never covered in the course. As such, it's likely there's a lot of general coding mistakes I've made here. If there are any improvements I can make to the code to make it cleaner, any suggestions would be much appreciated.
What can I do here to get my code to exit the do/while loop when player health/enemy health equals zero. Also, why are my dice functions returning the same rolls? I would have thought the rand function would be different between calls. Do I need to set them to different times in srand?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int health = 100;
int ref = 10;
int str = 10; 
int dex = 10;
int gdam = 10;
int mdam = 10;


int combat1();
int enemyroll();
int playerroll();

struct Goon{
    int health;
    int ref;
    int str;
    int dex;
    int rdam;
    int mdam;
};

int playerroll(){
    int roll = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return roll;
}

int enemyroll(){
    int roll = 0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return roll;
}

int combat1(){
    struct Goon g;
    g.health = 80;
    g.ref = 8;
    g.str = 6;
    g.dex = 6;
    g.rdam = 10;
    g.mdam = 8;

    int combatchoice = 0;
    int proll = 0;
    int eroll = 0;

    do{
        proll = playerroll();
        eroll = enemyroll();

        printf("Health: %d\n", health);
        printf("Enemy health: %d\n", g.health);

        printf("Choose fighting action\n");
        printf("[1]: Shoot Ranged Weapon\n");
        scanf("%d", &combatchoice);
        getchar();

        switch(combatchoice){
            case 1:
            if(ref + proll >= g.dex + eroll){
                printf("You rolled %d\n", proll);
                printf("Your enemy roled %d\n", eroll);
                printf("You hit your target!\n");
                g.health = g.health - gdam;
            }

            else if(ref + proll < g.dex + eroll){
                printf("You missed!\n");
            }

            break;
        }

    }

    while(health != 0 || g.health != 0);
}

int main(){

    combat1();

    return 0; 
}

I'm expecting that the code will exit the do/while loop after the enemy's health has been reduced to zero. I'm also expecting that playerroll() and enemyroll() would be different.
So far I've just tried changing variable names. I don't have much expirence with rand() so I wouldn't know where to start when troubleshooting.

Only call srand() once, at the beginning of the program. Not every time you want a random number.
